# How can I place the RN camera inside the outline of the face shape SVG?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to put the camera inside the outline of the faceshape svg, and it's not working. I would like to know how to put it inside of that svg.
Here's the code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
import { Svg, Path, G } from 'react-native-svg';

const CameraDisplay = () => {
  const [hasCameraPermission, setHasCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await RNCamera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasCameraPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }

  if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.preview}>
      <RNCamera
        style={styles.camera}
        type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
        ratio={'16:9'}
        ref={cameraRef}
      />

      {/* Mask overlay with the provided SVG path */}
      <Svg style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} viewBox="0 0 185 263">
        <G transform="translate(0.000000,263.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
          <Path d="M817 2234 c-253 -56 -412 -202 -474 -434 -21 -78 -23 -300 -5 -396 9
            -46 10 -85 2 -158 -13 -113 -2 -218 31 -292 12 -27 39 -99 60 -160 65 -192
            135 -311 237 -406 88 -81 137 -102 249 -106 86 -4 98 -2 158 27 153 71 280
            250 364 513 16 51 39 112 50 135 33 66 45 181 31 291 -9 74 -9 108 1 165 19
            104 17 307 -4 387 -56 214 -212 367 -432 425 -90 23 -190 27 -268 9z m258 -20
            c200 -51 352 -187 415 -374 29 -87 38 -287 18 -413 -11 -64 -12 -104 -6 -145
            6 -31 8 -102 6 -157 -4 -83 -9 -111 -32 -160 -15 -33 -43 -107 -62 -165 -58
            -179 -135 -312 -233 -403 -90 -83 -137 -102 -251 -102 -115 0 -160 19 -251
            102 -100 93 -177 225 -235 405 -14 46 -40 114 -57 153 -26 60 -31 85 -35 175
            -2 58 0 128 5 156 7 36 6 73 -3 125 -18 102 -17 299 1 378 43 183 165 324 342
            395 135 56 243 64 378 30z"/>
        </G>
      </Svg>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default CameraDisplay;
```

Here is the error for now:

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> TypeError: _reactNativeCamera.RNCamera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync is not a function (it is undefined)
> TypeError: _reactNativeCamera.RNCamera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync is not a function (it is undefined)

I expected the camera to be visually contained within the outlined area defined by the FaceShape SVG. However, the result was not as expected, and the camera did not appear within the SVG outline.
Here is the result I'm expecting
[FaceShape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4HXO.png)